# C# MonthCalendar

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I'm using the monthCalendar control from the toolbox in VS2010 and I am having difficulty in trying to make the calendars date "select-able". The date selected will be stored in an array with the rest of the input entered by the user. I felt that after a few hours of searching and finding results that did not relate to my problem that posting here would be the best solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
        int currentIndex;
        int arraySize = 0;
         Meeting[] meetingArray = new Meeting[100];

      private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Start.ToShortDateString();
    }

    private void calendarSaveChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Meeting m = new Meeting();
        m.title = textBoxTitle.Text;
        m.location = textBoxLocation.Text;
        m.startTime = textBoxStartTime.Text;
        m.endTime = textBoxEndTime.Text;
        m.notes = notesTextBox.Text;
        meetingArray[arraySize] = m;
        currentIndex = arraySize;
        arraySize++;
        meetingListBox.Enabled = true;
        textBoxTitle.Text = "";
        textBoxLocation.Text = "";
        textBoxStartTime.Text = "";
        textBoxEndTime.Text = "";
        notesTextBox.Text = "";

        meetingListBox.Items.Add(m);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "select-able"?  By code?  Through the GUI?  Adding some code will also help.

Comment: The monthCalendar control is in my form. WHen I run the program I want to be able to click on a date, the program recognizes the date you have chosen and when I hit my save button that date is saved into the array with the rest of the information that I ask the user to input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the monthCalendar in your form and right click. Select Properties. Then click Events and double-click DateSelected.

This will be generated by VS2010:

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Inside that method use `e.Start.ToShortDateString()` to capture the date that was selected and assign it to the appropriate index of your array.

**Update in regards to your question in the comments/ newly posted code:**

From what I can tell about your project, this might be the best solution for you (without having to completely restructure everything). Add another text box (name it dateBox). Then inside the DateSelected method add the following code:

```
dateBox.Text = e.Start.ToShortDateString();
```

Then inside your Click method that you have posted (assuming that your Meeting class has some sort of Date property) add the following code:

```
m.Date = dateBox.Text;
```

**Update**

Alternatively (and much more simply - I don't know why I didn't suggest this before), you could just define a global `string` in your form called dateStr and use that to hold the information for the date of the meeting until you click "save changes" and then assign it to `m.Date`. That would be a much more simpler solution than creating another textbox (which is probably what you're trying to avoid anyway).

Comment: I've edited in the coding. Could you maybe explain how to go about assigning the DateSelected method to the index?

Comment: What does your array look like? If it were say in the second position the code would look like this: `myArray[1] = e.Start.ToShortDateString();`

Answer (score 0):

The `MonthCalendar` control has a few properties you should be able to access: SelectionRange, SelectionStart, and SelectionEnd that contains the values of the date(s) selected.